# Setting Header Row in Itext Table

Tags: java, itext

I am creating a table using `itext`. Now while setting header row, if I set `table.setheaderrows(2)` then it sets first 2 rows as the header. But in my case I want only row no. 2 (not row number 1) to be reprinted while table is extended on the next page.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only work with a single `PdfPTable`, you can't define the second row as the header row that needs to be repeated. The trick is to use two `PdfPTable` instances with the same widths for the columns. The first one would be a single row table for the first header row, the second one would start with the header row that needs to be repeated. If you add two tables to a document, one right after the other, they are glued to each other and nobody will notice that it's not a single table.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I did it another way. I create 1st table with column count = 1 and added the another table in row 2. This saved the number of tables required as the 1st table now acts as the wrapper for all the tables. and also i didnt need to worry about the allignment issues

Comment: @Bruno How i can give heading for my table? I have N no. of table in my PDF and i want to give to each of the table

Comment: @NarendraJaggi Can you repeat that question in plain English. English isn't my native language and I don't understand what you're asking. Also: why do you hijack this question? Doesn't StackOverflow require that you post a new question?

Comment: Hi Bruno, SO banned me from asking new question. I am generating a PDF which have many PdfPTable(table object) which are dynamically generated.At last I am assiging the all table object to Document object.The issue is for all the tables i want to put heading. Is there any method by which i can assign the heading of table? Currently I am using alternate approach I am creating Paragraph and assigning to document directly

Comment: Adding headers to tables: use `setHeaderRows()` (see [table header examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/table-header)). Adding headers to pages: use page events (see [header examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/header)). SO never bans people without a reason, so you probably didn't play by the rules. For instance: when using iText, you should check the documentation on the official web site first.

Comment: Note that I still don't understand the question. Why do you create all tables in memory *before* adding any of them to the `Document`. Isn't that a waste of memory (bad programming practice). Also: why doesn't `setHeaderRows()` work for you?